# Cancellation Token Doesn't throw exception

Tags: c#, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

Good day.

I'm having a problem exiting a task with the cancellation token.

My program freezes when I get to the **token2.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();**.

Following it with the breakpoints is shows that the **token2** is cancelled, but the program doesn't revert back to the previous sub routine where I **try** and **catch**

```
 try
        {
            Task.Run(() => SendData_DoWork(_tokenSource3));
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            SetText("Communivation error with device");
            SetText("");
        }
        finally
        {
            token.Dispose();
        }

    }//comms routine

    //send Meter Address to communicate to meter
    private void SendData_DoWork(CancellationTokenSource token)
    {
        var token2 = token.Token;

        var _tokenSource4 = new CancellationTokenSource();

        try
        {
            timer.Interval = 10000;
            timer.Start();
            timer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;

            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();


            SerialConverter serialConverter = new SerialConverter();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            string newtext = null;

            newtext = $"/?{address}!\r\n";

            SetText("TX: " + newtext);
            byte[] newData = stringSend(newtext);

            stream.Write(newData, 0, newData.Length);

            Thread.Sleep(50);

            byte[] message = new byte[23];
            int byteRead;

            while (true)
            {
                byteRead = 0;

                try
                {
                    byteRead = stream.Read(message, 0, 23);
                    if (message[0] == (char)0x15)
                    {
                        token.Cancel();
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    token.Cancel();
                }

                if ((byteRead == 0))
                {
                    token.Cancel();
                }

                timer.Stop();
                timer.Dispose();

                ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
                string newresponse = encoder.GetString(serialConverter.convertFromSerial(message));
                SetText("RX: " + newresponse);

                if (newresponse[0].ToString() == SOH)
                {
                    token.Cancel();
                }

                if (newresponse != null)

                {
                    /* NEXT SUB ROUTINE*/

                }
                else { break; }
            }//while looop
        }//try 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            token.Cancel();
        }

        if (token2.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            timer.Dispose();
            token2.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();             
        }

    }//sendData subroutine
```

Answer (score 2):

You are launching a `Task`, and ignoring the result; the only time `Task.Run` would throw is if *the task-method is invalid, or enqueuing the operation itself failed*. If you want to know how `SendData_DoWork` ended, you'll need to *actually check the result of the task*, by capturing the result of `Task.Run` and awaiting it (preferably asynchronously, although if we're talking async, `SendData_DoWork` should probably also be async and return a `Task`).

Your `catch`/`finally` will probably be exited long before `SendData_DoWork` even *starts* - again: `Task.Run` just takes the time required to *validate and enqueue* the operation; not wait for it to happen.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I'm still busy with the code and I wanted to see if I get an error message should the network stream fail

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missunderstood how cancellation tokens are supposed to work. Your work method should take a `CancellationToken`, not a `CancellationTokenSource`. And it should call `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` *inside* the loop, not after. I would suspect that you would get some issues with multiple cancel calls to the same cancellation token.

Typically you would use a pattern something like like this:

```
public void MyCancelButtonHandler(...) => cts.Cancel();
public async void MyButtonHandler(...){
  try{
     cts = new CancellationTokenSource(); // update shared field
     await Task.Run(() => MyBackgroundWork(cts.Token));
  }
  catch(OperationCancelledException){} // Ignore
  catch(Exception){} // handle other exceptions
}
private void MyBackgroundWork(CancellationToken cancel){
  while(...){
    cancel.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    // Do actual work
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I did follow the tutorials and pass a `CancellationToken` when I was first trying this program. However when I did the `_tokensource.Cancel()` it didn't change the status of that token to cancelled.

Comment: @RSAAlanNewham That sounds unlikely to me. I find it more likely that you had multiple token sources and mixed them up. You can use "Make Object ID" in the debugger to confirm that you are actually looking at the same object".

Answer (score 0):

So in my particular case it seems like changing the sub-routines from `private async void ...`  to `private async Task` fixes the particular issue that I'm having.